# expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

```
    let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(
        data: "Your baby in week three\n" +
            "Three weeks into your pregnancy, and you might be wondering just how this little miracle occurred (as in the science bit we will assume you know the other part!). \n" +
            "\n" +
            "So here goes: the joining of your partner's sperm and your egg at the moment of conception resulted in a ball of cells (or a blastocyst, if you want to get really technical) which is now starting the 6 day journey from the fallopian tube to the uterus where it will attach itself to the lining of your womb and in nine months time, will result in a real live baby in your arms! \n" +
            "\n" +
            "Amazingly, although you will not know for a few months (or until the birth) the <b><font color=#00690c >sex of your baby</font></b> has already been determined. The fertilised egg contains <b><font color=#e3007b>46</font></b> chromosomes with <b><font color=#e3007b>23</font></b> from you and <b><font color=#e3007b>23</font></b> from the dad. You as mum will always provide the <b><font color=#e3007b>X</font></b> chromosome but the dad can provide an <b><font color=#e3007b>X</font></b> or <b><font color=#e3007b>Y</font></b> chromosome. <b><font color=#e3007b>XX</font></b> and you will be having a girl, <b><font color=#e3007b>XY</font></b> and you will have a little boy in 9 months time!".dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
        options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
        documentAttributes: nil)
    trimestercontent.attributedText = attrStr
```

am getting above error in title for using "+" operator to concat strings.
is there any method to solve this issue because i have a bulk data with "+" operator that concatenate strings.
please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create the literal string before calling the init method of `NSAttributedString`

```
let string = "Your baby in week three<br>" +
    "Three weeks into your pregnancy, and you might be wondering just how this little miracle occurred (as in the science bit we will assume you know the other part!). <br>" +
    "<br>" +
    "So here goes: the joining of your partner's sperm and your egg at the moment of conception resulted in a ball of cells (or a blastocyst, if you want to get really technical) which is now starting the 6 day journey from the fallopian tube to the uterus where it will attach itself to the lining of your womb and in nine months time, will result in a real live baby in your arms! <br>" +
    "<br>" +
"Amazingly, although you will not know for a few months (or until the birth) the <b><font color=#00690c >sex of your baby</font></b> has already been determined. The fertilised egg contains <b><font color=#e3007b>46</font></b> chromosomes with <b><font color=#e3007b>23</font></b> from you and <b><font color=#e3007b>23</font></b> from the dad. You as mum will always provide the <b><font color=#e3007b>X</font></b> chromosome but the dad can provide an <b><font color=#e3007b>X</font></b> or <b><font color=#e3007b>Y</font></b> chromosome. <b><font color=#e3007b>XX</font></b> and you will be having a girl, <b><font color=#e3007b>XY</font></b> and you will have a little boy in 9 months time!"

let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(
    data: string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
    options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer it worked fine, but   \n  (next line not working).
Whole sentence appears as a single paragraph.
please help!

Comment: Since you're dealing with HTML you need to use the `<br>` tag. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

split your string to some strings,and change to Swift 3.0 API

```
    let a = "Your baby in week three\nThree weeks into your pregnancy, and you might be wondering just how this little miracle occurred (as in the science bit we will assume you know the other part!). \n\n"
    let b = "So here goes: the joining of your partner's sperm and your egg at the moment of conception resulted in a ball of cells (or a blastocyst, if you want to get really technical) which is now starting the 6 day journey from the fallopian tube to the uterus where it will attach itself to the lining of your womb and in nine months time, will result in a real live baby in your arms! \n" +
    "\n"
    let c = "Amazingly, although you will not know for a few months (or until the birth) the <b><font color=#00690c >sex of your baby</font></b> has already been determined. The fertilised egg contains <b><font color=#e3007b>46</font></b> chromosomes with <b><font color=#e3007b>23</font></b> from you and <b><font color=#e3007b>23</font></b> from the dad. You as mum will always provide the <b><font color=#e3007b>X</font></b> chromosome but the dad can provide an <b><font color=#e3007b>X</font></b> or <b><font color=#e3007b>Y</font></b> chromosome. <b><font color=#e3007b>XX</font></b> and you will be having a girl, <b><font color=#e3007b>XY</font></b> and you will have a little boy in 9 months time!"
    let d = a+b+c

    let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString.init(data: d.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion:true)!, options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)

    trimestercontent.attributedText = attrStr
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with even less coupled and more compiler-friendly expression

```
let dataStr: String = [
    "Your baby in week three",
    "Three weeks into your pregnancy, and you might be wondering just how this little miracle occurred (as in the science bit we will assume you know the other part!). \n",
    "So here goes: the joining of your partner's sperm and your egg at the moment of conception resulted in a ball of cells (or a blastocyst, if you want to get really technical) which is now starting the 6 day journey from the fallopian tube to the uterus where it will attach itself to the lining of your womb and in nine months time, will result in a real live baby in your arms!",
    "Amazingly, although you will not know for a few months (or until the birth) the <b><font color=#00690c >sex of your baby</font></b> has already been determined. The fertilised egg contains <b><font color=#e3007b>46</font></b> chromosomes with <b><font color=#e3007b>23</font></b> from you and <b><font color=#e3007b>23</font></b> from the dad. You as mum will always provide the <b><font color=#e3007b>X</font></b> chromosome but the dad can provide an <b><font color=#e3007b>X</font></b> or <b><font color=#e3007b>Y</font></b> chromosome. <b><font color=#e3007b>XX</font></b> and you will be having a girl, <b><font color=#e3007b>XY</font></b> and you will have a little boy in 9 months time!"
].joined(separator: "\n")
```